# sql admin v1beta4 setDatabases throwing error

Tags: google-cloud-sql

When using setServicePath("sql/v1beta4/projects/") the following code produces an error when run:

```
ExportContext exportContext = new ExportContext().setDatabases(Arrays.asList("db123"));
```

For some reason it doesn't like setDatabases().

Any insights as to why this may be? A version of this code has been running on v1beta3 for months without issue.

Comment: You asked another question on StackOverflow about this. I would like to know what the error was and what you did to fix it. Thanks

Comment: I think the problem above was on v1beta4 rev1 - I waited and tried again on v1beta4 rev5 and it seems to work fine, EXCEPT that it takes over 1 minute for the operation status to change to DONE whereas it used to take only a few seconds.